# Moving revision from trunk to branch and then back again in svn

Tags: svn, version-control, merge

We have trunk as a our mainline of development and a branch for a future milestone being concurrently developed.

A change was committed to trunk in a single revision.

It has now been decided that this change should be part of the milestone developed in the branch, not in the trunk.

At a future point (after the work in trunk has been deployed) the branch will be merged into trunk.

I'm thinking about using this strategy. What difficulties will this cause in the later merge back to trunk? Is there a better method to use?

1. Merge the revision from trunk to the branch
2. Reverse merge the revision to remove it from trunk
3. Merge the revision back into trunk along with the other work when merging the branch back into trunk

Comment: That's how I'd do it. I'm wondering whether this question should be closed as "primarily opinion-based" however. Maybe this goes on programmers stack exchange? I don't use that site, much.

Comment: Thanks - I guess what I'm really asking is if I follow the above steps will eventually merging the revision back into trunk at a later date cause any difficulties with merge info/tree conflict?

Comment: I took the liberty of rephrasing your question with that in mind. Go ahead and change it if that's not what you're really asking.

Comment: Thanks - I should have just done that in the first place!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this I used the following steps:

1. Merged the revision from trunk to branch
2. Used Tortoise SVN's 'Revert changes from this revision' (accessed by right clicking on the revision in the log) to revert the changes in trunk
3. Merged the revision from step 1 from branch to trunk

The above worked without any problem.